# Angular 5: how to select RadioButtons after patchValue?

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormGroup with a few radio buttons, which is built dynamically like below:

```
toFormGroup(questions: Question[]) {
    const group: any = {};

    questions.forEach((question) => {
        group[question.id] = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
}
```

Here the corresponding html of the input radio

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let answer of answers">
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio"
           [formControlName]="question.id"
           [value]="answer"/>&nbsp;{{answer.name}}
</label>
</div>
```

The form is working fine when the user selects them by hand, but now I'm trying to add the possibility to resume an half-completed form, so the need to repopulate it back with the stored values.

A minimum example of how I (try to) repopulate it:

```
patchValues() {
    console.log('Form value before: ' + JSON.stringify(this.form.value));

    const value = {};
    value[1] = new Answer(99, 'YES');
    value[2] = new Answer(100, 'NO');

    console.log('Patching values: ' + JSON.stringify(value));

    this.form.patchValue(value);

    console.log('Form value after: ' + JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
}
```

What is working:

- the values of form.value are logged as expected with the patched values.
- the fields became valid (green left border) after the patch.

[image]

What is not working:

- the radio buttons remains blank (unchecked)

So now I'm wondering what's the missing part in order to restore the checked status of the radio buttons in addition to their values?

Comment: Where do you store the checked state of the radio button?

Comment: I'm just storing something like fieldName --> dirtyValue in the DB. Do I need to store something extra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was patching a **different** answer object as the value, from the one assigned to the corresponding [value] of the input when creating the form.

The new value was fetched from the DB based on an ID field previously stored, so it was not the same of object reference previously assigned to to the [value] of the input.

To get this result I had to store an array of answers in the Question object, than loop through question.answers for building the inputs, and assign each answer as the [value].
Then, in the patch, loop the stored question ==> answer and based on the ID of the answer, get the exact object reference from the answers of the Question object.

It may look strange, but it worked perfectly, with no need to have a [checked] expression.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the currently checked value (answer.name) as a string. Either in a single variable or in an object.

Let’s store it in an object, so you can control the state of many option groups.

```
States{question1: string, question2: string}
```

Bind the radio buttons of one group to the same field and set [checked]  to the current state of it.

```
<input type="radio"
       [formControlName]="question.id"
       [(ngModel)]="states.question1"
       [checked]="states.question1"
       [value]="answer.name"/>&nbsp;{{answer.name}}
```

You have to find some way to persist the states-object. Then you can restore the state of each option group.

Comment: Well, following your answer something moved...
The problem is that now they are both checked :(

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake by posting a solution for checkboxes instead of radio buttons. Corrected it.